# Modifying one instance of class affects another

Tags: python-3.5

Look at this simple snippet

```
from SwitchState import SwitchState

s1 = SwitchState()
s1.add(12345, True)

s2 = SwitchState()

print(s2.get_all())
```

Result is: `[(12345, True)]` !

I'm adding the item to `s1` but got it in `s2` too! What im doing wrong?

SwitchState.py

```
import struct


class SwitchState(object):

    _states = []

    def add(self, timestamp, state):
        self._states.append((timestamp, state))

    def get_all(self):
        return self._states
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both have the same `_states`, since it's a class attribute.

```
class ...
  def __init__(self):
    self._states = []
```

Comment: Oh, good. So I can define object level properies only in costructor?

Comment: The instance is the first argument passed to a method. If you don't have this argument then you don't have an instance.